# How can I debug my Perl Net::Telnet program?

Tags: perl, telnet

I am trying to automate telnet to a Linux box which doesn't require any authentication through [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::Telnet) Perl module. Here is a test script:

```
use strict;
use Net::Telnet;
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10, Errmode=>'die',
                               host=> '10.104.20.200', port => 2004,
                             ); 
$telnet->print('ls');
my $output = $telnet->waitfor('/\$ $/i');
print $output;
```

When I execute this script, I get the below error,

```
pattern match timed-out at telnetPerl.pl line 7.
```

As you could see, I am matching for any characters in `waitfor`. But I doubt whether the telnet connectivity happened in the first place.

Comment: Add `Debug => 1` to the constructor and post the output. Also, don't use indirect object notation; instead, use `my $telnet = Net::Telnet->new(...)`.

Comment: Although special considerations may make this secure, anonymous access via telnet is fundamentally flawed security-wise. Any trojan running on one of your 10.* hosts can find this via network scan and do all sorts of evil things. I hope you have at least chrooted your telnet user to some sandbox playground.

Answer (score 3):

The [Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Telnet) docs say under the entry for `waitfor()`:

> Use dump_log() to debug when this method keeps timing-out and you don't think it should.

What happened when you followed the doc's instructions? :)